# Is there a way to download multiple reports at once in Google Looker Studio?

Tags: automation, google-analytics, looker-studio

I have a list of reports in Looker Studio which looks like this in the dashboard:

[image]

Currently, to download multiple reports, you have to click on each report, click on share and click download report. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to download 50-60 of these reports at once, meaning that you have to download each one individually, taking up a large proportion of time.

Ideally, I would like to filter out the reports I need using the search bar and download all the reports listed under that search at once into a single folder.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem, or failing that, any links or resources that would help me achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, no nice native way to download them. A few ways to automate though.

1. You could inspect the API Google uses to download the reports and automate it right from the search page with JS. It looks pretty simple.
   This is the request:
   [image]
   And here's its POST payload:
   [image]
   The report IDs are present on the search result pages, so it should be trivial to iterate through the search results initiating downloads `.forEach()`. You may just be careful about timings. Not sure how the browser or the API would react to 20 near-simultaneous download requests.
2. Another option, let's say if the payload from the previous options changes too much between reports: You could write a script that would automatically click and download them all. I would suggest using something like ahk for it given how it tends to open new windows and popups. JS would be awkward to use, and it would probably have to be powered with something like grease monkey or just a raw extension that is capable of keeping the context inbetween tabs/pages.
3. You could use a proper BI tool like Looker instead of the simplified Looker Studio, but that entails ETL. If you don't have existing ETL pipelines in place then you probably don't want to go this route.
4. A very limited solution would be setting up scheduled emails and download the reports from the emails, but that only works if you need to do it regularly for the same reports.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you expand on point 1)? Do you mean writing a POST request using the Fetch API using the details from the payload which you mentioned? If so, would you use an external program to do this or just paste the script into the console?

Comment: yes, that's about how I would do it. a POST request via fetch. You don't want an external program. You want to do it right in the browser console. That's important. It's way way easier to debug in the console plus the browser will already have your authenticated session with GA running, so you won't need to bother authenticating, plus the browser knows how to download files, which the third party tool might not know.

Comment: If you start working on it in a public repo under a permissive license, I'll be glad to help you with the code too

Comment: I agree with your approach, I can't be bothered with authentication... thanks for offering to help - I have started a JSFiddle here - I have had to cross out some details in the link and the Cookie for confidentiality reasons: https://jsfiddle.net/OzzKuragin/ov9b4gpu/6/

Comment: i just tried a POST with one report and it did not work.  {"errorStatus":{"code":3}}  I think you will run into SAMEORIGIN issues

Comment: Coulld you post the code for that request ?